# add precision-recall curves to plot using a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, precision-recall

I have a dataframe with precision and recall for many classifiers, each one ran with 4 different values of the confidence threshold:

```
    MODEL   CONFIDENCE_THR  PRECISION   RECALL
0   Model1  0.25    0.992647    0.950704
1   Model1  0.45    1.000000    0.929577
2   Model1  0.35    0.992537    0.936620
3   Model1  0.30    0.992593    0.943662
4   Model2  0.45    0.992647    0.950704
5   Model2  0.30    0.992647    0.950704
6   Model2  0.35    0.992647    0.950704
7   Model2  0.25    0.992701    0.957746
8   Model3  0.30    0.978417    0.957746
9   Model3  0.35    0.978102    0.943662
.
.
.
```

I would like to create a Matplotlib plot in JupyterLab, and add a precision-recall curve for each model. Since the list of models may change in the future, I would like to do this with a Python function, instead than hardcoding the model names in the Matplotlib code. I wrote something like

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib widget

df = pd.read_csv("results.csv")

plt.title('Precision-Recall curves')
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')

def plot_precision_recall_curve(df, model, plt):
    df = df.loc[df['MODEL'] == model, ['MODEL', 'PRECISION', 'RECALL']]
    plt.plot(df['RECALL'], df["PRECISION"], 'b', label = model)  

plot_precision_recall_curve(df, 'Model1', plt)
plt.show()
```

But I get an empty plot, with the message

```
No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.
```

Also, note that in my code I tried to plot the precision-recall curve of a single model, but actually I would like to add to the same plot the precision-recall curves of all models included in the dataframe. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code, move `plt.legend()` after you plot something, best to be before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.title('Precision-Recall curves')
plot_precision_recall_curve(df, 'Model1', plt)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.show()
```

On the other note, are you open to `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='RECALL', y='PRECISION', hue='MODEL')
```

Output:

[image]